# Mysterious bottom border

Tags: css, image, html-table, border

I promised to change the logo on an e-commerce site, though it'd take a few minutes, but it has taken many hours. So I'm hoping someone with more experience with CSS can help me out.

This is the site:
http://varuosad.ee/

I can't seem to make the `<tr>` containing the image as high as the image (155px), no matter how high I make the image, the `<tr>` has a height exactly 2 pixels higher. From the 2 pixels I guessed it's the user agent style sheet with border-spacing: 2px, but overriding that didn't help.

This is the offending part (it's the block with language selection and the main logo):

```
<table class="table_right">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub_row_1 bg_ylemine_riba">
        <a href="/">
          <img src="/assets/img/bg_ylemine_riba.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="/changelanguage/en">
          <img class="lang_right" src="/assets/img/eng.gif" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="/changelanguage/et">
          <img class="lang_left" src="/assets/img/est.gif" alt="">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub_row_2">
        <a href='/'>
          <img class='soov_logo' src='/assets/img/logo_uus.png'>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried these:

```
border: 0px;
border-spacing: 0px;
border: none;
border: 0 none;
border-width: 0px;
margin-bottom: -1px;
max-height: 155px;
height: 155px;
```

And many more different properties and values, but it seems like nothing overrides what I need to. Even worse, I don't really know what to override, I'm just guessing it's the border of the tr, td, a or img... Maybe it's the font size or something else entirely.

I'll be grateful for any reply. If it can't be done, it can't be done, I'll just give up and move on to web-sites not designed using tables.

Comment: The table cell is inheriting a height of `157px` from `.center_div_table td table.table_right td.sub_row_2`.

Comment: You can add `display:block;` to the `tr` and `td` element

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, I can't believe I missed the 157-pixel css rule, but that didn't fix it in any case. Block also changed nothing. The image is still 155 pixels high, the <a> around it is for some reason 14 pixels high (I'm guessing 12 for the font and another 2 px for the strange border-like things), overlapping the image with 12 of it's pixels and using the remaining 2 pixels to heighten the <td> containing both the <a> and the <img> to 157 pixels. I really can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: Also, using:
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;

Makes it align nicely, but still doesn't get rid of the extra space.

Comment: can you provide a more helpful title for that question??

Comment: Pretty sure that ship has sailed? Meaning I can't change the title.

Comment: @randy Your advice helped me with another <div>, so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to the image.  This space is the space below the baseline.